# MS Chart label in different color only if it is outside of series

Tags: c#, .net, mschart, series

**Context:**
I am working with MS Chart and need to make my series label is black if value is callout (repositioned out of the series).

Actually, The series labels are showing inside series and I am updating label colors according to series color darkness/brightness factors. If Series color is dark then label color will be white in contra, if series has lighter color then the label color will be white using following code

```
    double brightnessWhite = 255;
    double brightnessBackColor = (backColor.R * 299 + backColor.G * 587 + backColor.B * 114) / 1000;
    double brightnessForeColor = (foreColor.R * 299 + foreColor.G * 587 + foreColor.B * 114) / 1000;

    double factor = brightnessForeColor - brightnessBackColor;
    double whiteFactor = brightnessWhite - brightnessBackColor;

    if (factor <= 110 && factor >= -140) // text not legible
    {
        color = (whiteFactor >= 110 && whiteFactor <= -140) ? Color.Black : Color.White;
    }

    return color;
```

**Problem:**
issue here starts when series size is much smaller then label then label is repositioned into outside because of SmartLabelStyle callout property is enabled. If my series has darker color and very small then White color label will be drawn outside of series on chart area is also white so label will no longer visible. (Image has been attached below)

I can't not whole label's color to gray or some other color because it will affect all labels if thay are not outside the series. How the label can be shown in Black color only if label is repositioned out of series.

### [image: left is a picture with visible label and right is with white label on white background]

Comment: So, do you use the callout colors? (`CalloutBack/ForeColor`)

Comment: Callout color don't have `ForColor` property.